# How do I use hexadecimal color strings in Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, colors, hex

How do I convert a *hexadecimal color string* like **`#b74093`** to a `Color` in Flutter?

I want to use a HEX color code in Dart.

Comment: in google chrome devtools you can quickly get the decimal numbers for a hex-style color; just click on the tiny color rectangle in the styles sidebar; in the popup you can switch the representation between HSLA, RGBA, HEX by clicking the chevron. Then you can use `Color.fromRGBO()`

Comment: Nice, but this is a programmer website so we generally want to know how to do it in code.

Answer (score 966, accepted):

In Flutter, the **[`Color` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)** only accepts ***integers** as parameters*, or there is the possibility to use the named constructors [`fromARGB`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.fromARGB.html) and [`fromRGBO`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.fromRGBO.html).

So we only need to convert the string `#b74093` to an integer value. Also we need to respect that **opacity** always needs to be specified.
`255` (full) opacity is represented by the hexadecimal value `FF`. This already leaves us with **`0xFF`**. Now, we just need to append our color string like this:

```dart
const color = const Color(0xffb74093); // Second `const` is optional in assignments.
```

The letters can by choice be capitalized or not:

```dart
const color = const Color(0xFFB74093);
```

---

If you want to use *percentage opacity values*, you can replace the first `FF` with the values from [this table](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e#hex-opacity-values) (also works for the other color channels).

### Extension class

[Starting with Dart `2.6.0`, you can create an `extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58288266/6509751) for the `Color` class that lets you use hexadecimal color strings to create a `Color` object:

```dart
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// String is in the format "aabbcc" or "ffaabbcc" with an optional leading "#".
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }

  /// Prefixes a hash sign if [leadingHashSign] is set to `true` (default is `true`).
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

The `fromHex` method could also be declared in a `mixin` or `class` because the `HexColor` name needs to be explicitly specified in order to use it, but the extension is useful for the `toHex` method, which can be used implicitly. Here is an example:

```dart
void main() {
  final Color color = HexColor.fromHex('#aabbcc');

  print(color.toHex());
  print(const Color(0xffaabbcc).toHex());
}
```

#### Disadvantage of using hex strings

Many of the other answers here show how you can dynamically create a `Color` from a hex string, like I did above. However, doing this means that the color cannot be a `const`.
Ideally, you would assign your colors the way I explained in the first part of this answer, which is more efficient when instantiating colors a lot, which is usually the case for Flutter widgets.

Comment: You can't have static method extension in dart yet https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/723

Comment: I'm just surprised that you can pass 0xFF as part of an int

Comment: @HamishJohnson `0x` just indicates that the following digits will be parsed as a hexadecimal 

Comment: Is there any way to use 50% or any % of these colors? Like something Color(0xFF183451)[50]?

Comment: @Ankit You can use [this table](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e#hex-opacity-values) and replace the `FF` in the leading `0xFF` of your `Color` object with the value you need. So in your case that would be `Color(0x80183451)`.

Comment: How do I convert `#0ff` this string?, It has only three digits

Comment: @BalajiRamadoss I think the standard convention would make this `0xff00ffff` and you could write a function for it.

Comment: Yes thanks, I figured it out, I have to double the characters "0ff" to "00ffff"

Comment: Now a days the best way to do this is to use the flutter hex color plugin from ***pub.dev*** and the import the package.

Comment: @MNBWorld I highly disagree with that sentiment. The package only implements a version of the extension class from my answer with less features. This leads to poorer customization of how you want to handle HEX codes (which might be specific to your app). And in general, it is preferrable to use the `const` constructors with `Color`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Regarding the cache/const problem... would it work if you set a static property `Map<String, Color>` within the extension to store the hex strings? (check if the hex string key exists in that static property before calculating?)

Comment: @alexsmith Then you would still have to look up the hash map to obtain the color. I doubt that you will gain much from that and it will certainly not be `const` and can therefore not be used in `const` values.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Yes it won't be `const` indeed but it seems you're implying that looking up the hash map is also somewhat an expensive task. Is it?

Comment: @alexsmith I am not implying that either of the operations is expensive. However, you will not be able to take advantage of `const` values.

Answer (score 280):

The `Color` class expects an ARGB integer. Since you try to use it with an *RGB* value, represent it as *int* and prefix it with `0xff`.

```
Color mainColor = Color(0xffb74093);
```

---

If you get annoyed by this and still wish to use strings, you can extend `Color` and add a string constructor

```
class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Usage

```
Color color1 = HexColor("b74093");
Color color2 = HexColor("#b74093");
Color color3 = HexColor("#88b74093"); // If you wish to use ARGB format
```

Comment: the HexColor class did not work for MaterialColor for me, it keeps complaining of the second parameter. Please help here

Comment: `.toUpperCase()` giving error. Removed it and working now

Answer (score 102):

If you want to use the hexadecimal code of a color which is in the format #123456, then it is very easy to do. Create a variable of type Color and assign the following values to it.

```
Color myHexColor = Color(0xff123456)

// Here you notice I use the 0xff and that is the opacity or transparency
// of the color and you can also change these values.
```

Use myHexColor and you are ready to go.

If you want to change the opacity of color direct from the hexadecimal code, then change the *ff* value in *0xff* to the respective value from the table below. (alternatively you can use

```
myHexColor.withOpacity(0.2)
```

it is easier way to do it. 0.2 is mean 20% opacity)

#### Hexadecimal opacity values

```
100% — FF

95% — F2

90% — E6

85% — D9

80% — CC

75% — BF

70% — B3

65% — A6

60% — 99

55% — 8C

50% — 80

45% — 73

40% — 66

35% — 59

30% — 4D

25% — 40

20% — 33

15% — 26

10% — 1A

5% — 0D

0% — 00
```

Comment: It's a good idea to save this reference, although the .withOpacity(0.2) is useful enough i most of the cases.

Comment: This is grate but sometimes It shows whats going below the widgets for example when `SliverAppBar` scrolls it shows whats below that widget because of I'm reducing the opacity. Is there anyway to fade the color without reducing opacity.

Comment: @nipunravisara get the hex of the color and use 100% opacity

Comment: @ZakriaKhan Thanks actually I found a way. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65856982/generate-custom-color-shades-from-parent-color-in-flutter/65857376#65857376

Answer (score 75):

**How to use a hexadecimal color code #B74093 in Flutter**

Simply remove the `#` sign from the hexadecimal color code and add 0xFF with the color code inside the Color class:

`#b74093` will become `Color(0xffb74093)` in Flutter

`#B74093` will become `Color(0xFFB74093)` in Flutter

The `ff or FF` in `Color(0xFFB74093)` defines the opacity.

**[Hexadecimal colors example with all opacity types in Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/d1b1bcd13e74d0296a32e15c437aab84?)**

[image]

Answer (score 57):

Easy way:

```dart
String color = yourHexColor.replaceAll('#', '0xff');
```

Usage:

```dart
Container(
  color: Color(int.parse(color)),
)
```

Answer (score 31):

Thanks for asking this question, simples solution is as:

**// Color to Hex String**

```
colorToHexString(Color color) {
  return '#FF${color.value.toRadixString(16).substring(2, 8)}';
}
```

**// Hex String to Color**

```
hexStringToColor(String hexColor) {
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
  }
  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}
```

**// How to call function**

```
String hexCode = colorToHexString(Colors.green);
Color bgColor = hexStringToColor(hexCode);
print("$hexCode = $bgColor");
```

Enjoy code and help others :)

Answer (score 28):

A simple function without using a class:

```
Color _colorFromHex(String hexColor) {
  final hexCode = hexColor.replaceAll('#', '');
  return Color(int.parse('FF$hexCode', radix: 16));
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
Color color1 = _colorFromHex("b74093");
Color color2 = _colorFromHex("#b74093");
```

Comment: Thansk to @jeroen-meijer for the edit. In fact you can use this one liner as well if you feel fancy `Color(int.parse('#000000'.replaceAll('#', '0xff')))`

Answer (score 27):

To convert from a hexadecimal string to integer, do:

```
int hexToInt(String hex)
{
  int val = 0;
  int len = hex.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int hexDigit = hex.codeUnitAt(i);
    if (hexDigit >= 48 && hexDigit <= 57) {
      val += (hexDigit - 48) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 65 && hexDigit <= 70) {
      // A..F
      val += (hexDigit - 55) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 97 && hexDigit <= 102) {
      // a..f
      val += (hexDigit - 87) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else {
      throw new FormatException("Invalid hexadecimal value");
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

Call example:

```
Color color = new Color(hexToInt("FFB74093"));
```

Comment: Lots of magic numbers. Aren't named constants supported in this language / environment?

Comment: And `(1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)))` is repeated three times.

Comment: This can be done much easier: `int hexToInt(String hex){ return int.parse('0x$hex'); }`

Answer (score 26):

There is another solution. If you store your color as a normal hexadecimal string and don't want to add opacity to it (leading "FF"):

1. Convert your hexadecimal string to int
   To convert a hexadecimal string to an integer, do one of the following:

   ```
    var myInt = int.parse(hexString, radix: 16);
   ```

   or

   ```
    var myInt = int.parse("0x$hexString");
   ```

   as a prefix of 0x (or -0x) will make *int.parse* default to a radix of 16.
2. Add opacity to your color via code

   ```
    Color color = new Color(myInt).withOpacity(1.0);
   ```

Comment: I needed the "leading FF" for Flutter's `ThemeData`.

Comment: I like this solution for its simplicity, but as @creativecreatorormaybenot mentioned, the leading FF is still required.

Comment: - withOpacity is important

Answer (score 21):

This was the solution for me:

```
String hexString = "45a3df";
Color(int.parse("0xff${hexString}"));
```

It was the only way that didn't require additional steps.

Comment: your solution is working for me. Are there any downsides, anyone?

Comment: Or `Color(int.parse(hexString.replaceFirst('#', '0xff')))` if I know for sure that the input hex string is in `#RRGGBB` format (such as `#45a3df`).

Comment: Do not forget that hex can contain 8 digits

Answer (score 16):

Use [hexcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor) for bringing hexadecimal colors to the Dart hexcolorPlugin:

```
hexcolor: ^2.0.3
```

**Sample usage**

```
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Hexcolor('#34cc89'),
    ),
    child: Center(
        child: Text(
            'Running on: $_platformVersion\n',
            style: TextStyle(color: Hexcolor("#f2f2f2")),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 15):

In Flutter, to create a color from RGB with alpha, use:

```
return new Container(
  color: new Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
);
```

How to use hexadecimal color:

```
return new Container(
  color: new Color(0xFF4286f4),
);
// 0xFF -> the opacity (FF for opaque)
// 4286f4 -> the hexadecimal color
```

Hexadecimal color with opacity:

```
return new Container(
  color: new Color(0xFF4286f4).withOpacity(0.5),
);
```

// Or change the "FF" value

```
100% — FF
 95% — F2
 90% — E6
 85% — D9
 80% — CC
 75% — BF
 70% — B3
 65% — A6
 60% — 99
 55% — 8C
 50% — 80
 45% — 73
 40% — 66
 35% — 59
 30% — 4D
 25% — 40
 20% — 33
 15% — 26
 10% — 1A
 5% — 0D
 0% — 00
```

For more, see the official documentation page, *[Color class - dart:ui library - Dart API](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html)*.

Answer (score 12):

You can use this

```
Color getColorFromColorCode(String code){
  return Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Simple **extension** based on @Serdar answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57943307/4899849

```
extension HexString on String {
  int getHexValue() => int.parse(replaceAll('#', '0xff'));
}
```

**Usage:**

```
'#b74093'.getHexValue()
```

Answer (score 11):

To use hex color code inside flutter you can simply use following trick:

**Example :**

```
Your color code : #F8485E
```

Now remove **#** and use following declaration:

```
Color(0xFFF8485E) //Add 0xFF and Replace # with your hex code
```

Happy Fluttering!

Answer (score 10):

#### File *utils.dart*

```
///
/// Convert a color hex-string to a Color object.
///
Color getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll('#', '');

  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor;
  }

  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}
```

#### Example usage

```
Text(
  'Hello, World!',
  style: TextStyle(
    color: getColorFromHex('#aabbcc'),
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  )
)
```

Answer (score 10):

There isn't any need to use functions.

For example, to give a color to a container using colorcode:

```
Container
(
    color:Color(0xff000000)
)
```

Here the `0xff` is the format followed by color code

Answer (score 7):

For general reference. There is a simpler way using the library **Supercharged**. Although you can use extension methods with all solutions mentioned, you find practical user library toolkit.

```
"#ff00ff".toColor(); // Painless hex to color
"red".toColor(); // Supports all web color names
```

Easier, right?

[Supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged)

Answer (score 7):

Add this function in your file -

```
Color parseColor(String color) {
  String hex = color.replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hex.isEmpty) hex = "ffffff";
  if (hex.length == 3) {
    hex = '${hex.substring(0, 1)}${hex.substring(0, 1)}${hex.substring(1, 2)}${hex.substring(1, 2)}${hex.substring(2, 3)}${hex.substring(2, 3)}';
  }
  Color col = Color(int.parse(hex, radix: 16)).withOpacity(1.0);
  return col;
}
```

And use it like -

```
Container(
    color: parseColor("#b74093")
)
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to convert it into an integer. For example, *#BCE6EB*. You would add *0xFF* and you would then remove the hashtag making it:

0XFFBCE6EB

Then let’s say you were to implement it by doing:

`backgroundColor: Color(0xffbce6eb)`

If you can only use a hexadecimal then I suggest using the [Hexcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor) package.

Answer (score 5):

`"#b74093"`? OK...

#### To HEX Recipe

```
int getColorHexFromStr(String colorStr)
{
  colorStr = "FF" + colorStr;
  colorStr = colorStr.replaceAll("#", "");
  int val = 0;
  int len = colorStr.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int hexDigit = colorStr.codeUnitAt(i);
    if (hexDigit >= 48 && hexDigit <= 57) {
      val += (hexDigit - 48) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 65 && hexDigit <= 70) {
      // A..F
      val += (hexDigit - 55) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else if (hexDigit >= 97 && hexDigit <= 102) {
      // a..f
      val += (hexDigit - 87) * (1 << (4 * (len - 1 - i)));
    } else {
      throw new FormatException("An error occurred when converting a color");
    }
  }
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Lots of magic numbers. Aren't named constants supported in this language / environment?

Comment: What this is a bad answer and bad coding honestly, so many magic numbers, too much code for a one liner

Answer (score 5):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HexToColor extends Color{
  static _hexToColor(String code) {
    return int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000;
  }
  HexToColor(final String code) : super(_hexToColor(code));
}
```

Import the new class and use it like this:

```
HexToColor('#F2A03D')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use hexadecimal numbers with the fromRGB constructor:

```
Color.fromRGBO(0xb7, 0x40, 0x93, 1),
```

Answer (score 5):

As the [Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html) constructor does not support **hexadecimal string**, so we should find other alternatives.

**There are several possibilities:**

**1-** The first one is to create a small function that will allow you ***to convert a color hex-string to a Color object***.

**Code:**

```
   Color colorFromHex(String hexColor) {
   final hexCode = hexColor.replaceAll('#', '');
   if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = 'FF' + hexColor; // FF as the opacity value if you don't add it.
   }
  return Color(int.parse('FF$hexCode', radix: 16));
}
```

**Usage**:

```
 Container(
          color: colorFromHex('abcdff'),
          child: Text(
            'Never stop learning',
            style: TextStyle(color: colorFromHex('bbffffcc')),
          ),
        )
```

**2-** The second possibility is to use the **[supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged) package.** [Supercharged](https://pub.dev/packages/supercharged) brings all the comfort features from languages like Kotlin to all Flutter developers.

Add the dependency supercharged: `^1.X.X` (find recent version) to your project and start using Supercharged everywhere:

```
import 'package:supercharged/supercharged.dart';
```

Now ,transform any String to colors

**Code :**

```
"#ff00ff".toColor(); // Painless hex to color
"red".toColor(); // Supports all web color names
```

You can also use the **[hexcolor](https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor)** package which is also great.

Answer (score 4):

While the existing answer is correct, the solution is overcomplicated. Dart has simpler methods to convert hexadecimal strings to `Color`s.

This function converts a hex string to an `integer`

```dart
int hexToInteger(String hex) => int.parse(hex, radix: 16);
```

Usage:

```dart
final red = Color(hexToInteger('FFFF0000'));
```

You can also extend `String` to convert to a `Color`

```dart
extension StringColorExtensions on String {
  Color toColor() => Color(hexToInteger(this));
}
```

Usage:

```dart
final red = 'FFFF0000'.toColor();
```

You can read more about these functions in this [blog post](https://www.christianfindlay.com/blog/flutter-hexadecimal-colors).

Answer (score 3):

You can click on Color Widget and it tells you with much deeper information what those letters stand for.

You can also use the Color.fromARGB() method to create custom colors which is much easier to me. Use the [Flutter Doctor Color Picker](https://flutter-color-picker.herokuapp.com/) website to pick any color you want for your Flutter application.

Answer (score 3):

I have created this Flutter extention function of String class.. kinda useful if you also hate 0xFFF

```
extension on String {
  Color parse() {
    var hexColor = this.replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
    }
    if (hexColor.length == 8) {
      return Color(int.parse("0x$hexColor"));
    }
  }
}
```

you can use to any hexadecimal color code string as follows...

```
'#bdbdbd'.parse() // this will return Color class object which you use in widget...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package [from_css_color](https://pub.dev/packages/from_css_color) to get `Color` out of a hexadecimal string. It supports both three-digit and six-digit RGB hexadecimal notation.

```dart
Color color = fromCSSColor('#ff00aa')
```

For optimisation sake, create a Color instance once for each color and store it somewhere for later usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this material_color_gen package it works like a charm

```
material_color_gen: ^2.0.0
```

Using :

```
import 'package:material_color_gen/material_color_gen.dart';
primarySwatch: Color(0xFFFF0000).toMaterialColor()
```

This is a HexColor example: #ff0000
Change # with 0xFF result is: 0xFFFF0000

Official link :
https://pub.dev/packages/material_color_gen

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the flutter hex color plugin from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/)
and the import the package.

```
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';
```

and then use that in this particular way.

```
Text( 
     'Running on: $_platformVersion\n',
      style: TextStyle(color: HexColor("#f2f2f2")),
    ),
Text(
      "Hex From Material  $textColor",
       style: TextStyle(color: ColorToHex(Colors.teal)),
    ),
```

particular plugin [here](https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor).

Answer (score 1):

// call this line for set color
color: HexColor(HexColor.Primarycolor)

**i have create a class HexColor and defile all color in this class. this is 100% working code**

```
class HexColor extends Color {
    static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");

      if (hexColor.length == 6) {
       hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
       }

    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
   }

 static var Primarycolor="FF3E3F";

  static var Accentcolor="b74093";

  static var white="b74093";

static var black="b74093";

HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small console utility for converting a string:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  while (true) {
    var line = stdin.readLineSync(encoding: utf8);

    print(HexColor.fromHex(line!));
  }
}

class HexColor {
  static fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hexadecimal color desperately in your application, there is one simple step you can follow:

1. Convert your hexadecimal color into RGB format simply from [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html).
2. Get your RGB values.
3. In Flutter, you have an simple option to use RGB color:

   `Color.fromRGBO(r_value, g_value, b_value, opacity)` will do the job for you.
4. Go ahead and tweak *O_value* to get the color you want.