# What is Canvas.save and Canvas.restore?

Tags: flutter, dart, skia

I am wondering [why and when](https://twitter.com/wyldebill00/status/1214744228259082240?s=20) you would use [`Canvas.save`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/save.html), [`Canvas.restore`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/restore.html), and maybe even [`Canvas.saveLayer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/saveLayer.html).
I have heard that they are really useful, but I do not know when to use them.

Comment: fun fact : im using your repo and also wonder what save and store did rofl ( funvas btw )

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`Canvas.save` and `Canvas.saveLayer` work slightly differently, but they both have the same counterpart:

### [`Canvas.restore`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/restore.html)

This allows you to restore the state before the most recent entry on the save stack, i.e. it "*Pops the current save stack*". This means that any transformations and clips done to the canvas in the current state will be removed and if `saveLayer` was used, the saved layer will be composited into the canvas (the draw order will remain the same).

### [`Canvas.save`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/save.html)

As I mentioned earlier, this allows you to save the state the canvas is in. You can do any **transformation** and **clips** you want and those will be removed using `restore`:

```dart
canvas.save();

canvas.transform(..); // Transforms the canvas, which will affect the draw call.
canvas.drawRect(...); // Affected by the transform.

canvas.restore();

canvas.drawRect(...); // Not affected by the transform.
```

You can use any number of `save` before `restore` and the stack will remember all entries, i.e. `restore` will always pop the most recent entry.

#### When would I use this?

Example: if you wanted to rotate a single piece when drawing a bigger picture, you can simply do the rotation inside a `save`-`restore` block and draw something without the rotation on top afterwards.

Note that all *children* of a `RenderObject` will use the same [`PaintingContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/PaintingContext-class.html), i.e. the same `Canvas`. So if you transform the canvas in a single child, it will also be transformed for all other children that draw afterwards. This is potentially unwanted behavior and the reason why you always want to `save` and `restore` the canvas state.

### [`Canvas.saveLayer`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/saveLayer.html)

This is a bit more complicated and I urge you to read the *comprehensive* documentation of this method. Btw, `saveLayer` [does not work in *Flutter web* as of January, 2019](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48417).

The basic difference between `saveLayer` and `save` is that `saveLayer` will composite the layer upon usage of `restore`. For a simple example, I constructed this snippet *without* **`bounds`** (which is why `null` is passed), which will save the whole canvas:

```dart
canvas.drawRect(rect, Paint()..color = const Color(0xffff0000)); // Draws a red rect.
canvas.saveLayer(null, Paint()..blendMode = BlendMode.multiply); // Saves the whole canvas.

canvas.drawRect(
  rect.shift(const Offset(20, 20)),
  Paint()..color = const Color(0xff0000ff), // Draws a blue rect.
);

canvas.restore(); // Composites the red rect into the blue rect.
```

[image: Screen capture]

Note that the blue rect will still be composited above the red rect.

This example could also be achieved without using `saveLayer` because the [`Paint.blendMode`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Paint/blendMode.html) I used can also be passed to [`Canvas.drawRect`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawRect.html). However, when using e.g. a [`TextPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextPainter-class.html), you cannot pass blend modes. Additionally, `saveLayer` allows you to pass bounds, which gives far more possibilites (read the documentation for more information, also about ***clips***). **Clipping** is actually probably the most useful operation in combination with `saveLayer` - I did not include it in order to have a simple example.

This is how the example would look without `saveLayer`:

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: I appreciate your interesting questions and answers. But I was wondering why you create these questions and reply to them immediately. Wouldn't it make more sense to write an article about it?

Comment: @JoãoSoares Nice question :) So why I create them: [This](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and with this one I answered a [question on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wyldebill00/status/1214744228259082240?s=20) - I actually linked to it in my question. Generally, I do this when I ask myself something and think it would be useful for others to find out what my research has shown. For example, turns out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50081213/6509751) was extremely popular *after* I asked about it - I was able to help many people.

Comment: @JoãoSoares As I accept my own answers in that case (to show that the question has an answer), I could also write articles, yes. I will be getting into writing articles - I recently wrote [this "test" article](https://medium.com/@creativecreatorormaybenot/sites-shamelessly-ripping-off-stack-overflow-content-4c10597ade57?source=friends_link&sk=e6b6e61bf938be6495208cfdad1f075b) (maybe it is interesting to you). However, I see a few benefits to writing an answer in this article style on SO: it is more concise and easier to find, probably helps more people and there are less expectations.

Comment: @JoãoSoares I will try to write an article about render objects and stuff (in connection to the Flutter Clock challenge) soon and then I can see how that works out for me. If you have any feedback about my style of writing or w/e or any questions in general, just HMU. I am glad to answer them :)

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I am definitely interested. I love Flutter and have dedicated a lot of time to it. Learning more is always great and it looks like you have a lot to teach. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @JoãoSoares This is great to hear :) I think that most of the topics that would be discussed in articles are rather lengthy and a decent commitment to cover - like your video tutorials, which I appreciate. In that sense, I am not sure if I see myself as a "teacher" enough. I try to share my experience whenever I can to help out others and because I believe in this community. The StackOverflow community is very helpful and the same applies to people making tutorials and writing articles! I like about SO that writing an answer is not a huge commitment to make (:

Comment: Thank you for this well written answer. As you said so yourself, the example you provided for `Canvas.saveLayer` is not a good use for saveLayer. In the flutter docs, they gave an example of "having multiple semi-transparent objects", if those were drawn separately, the overlapping parts will be darker than usual. With `saveLayer` we can then draw objects with opaque paint on a saved layer, then apply opacity in one go. I think that would be a good example but I couldn't find a way to apply arbitrary alpha value when blending. Do you think what they said is actually doable?