# What type of color is this 0xfffbb448?

Tags: flutter

I am learning flutter in most of my UI tutorial they are using this type of color code

```
0xfffbb448
```

I need to know what type is it? Where I can find these color codes? Try to find on google but not able to find which type of color code is this.

Comment: Googling "flutter colors" led me to the documentation in 2 clicks. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html

Comment: Googling is essential for being a developoer.

Comment: I think you should google before create this question

Answer (score 3):

The color code `0xFFfbb448` is how you define a hexadecimal color in flutter. It starts with 0x, then 2 digits that represents the opacity/transparency, and then the last 6 digits is the color code Hex #.

You can get the 6 digit color code # from many sources such as https://htmlcolorcodes.com/ or https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

You may also find the 2 digits transparency code from sources such as https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

An example:
`Colors.blue.withopacity(0.5)` would be the same as `Color(0x800000FF)`
where 80 means 50% opacity, and #0000FF is Hex color code for blue

There are many sources out there and similar questions like the below link to find out more.
[How do I use hexadecimal color strings in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter)