# Add hexa colors instead of Flutter defaults color values

Tags: flutter

I wanted to use Hexa color code for my flutter app using backgroundColor: Colors.#34A123. But  I can only pickup flutter defaults values

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CRICKDOM MOBILE'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        leading:IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.menu
          ),
          onPressed: (){},
        ),
 
        ],
    );

  }
}



``
```

Comment: backgroundColor: Colors.#A231B3, not worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use hexadecimal color strings in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one of the constructors of [Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html) class.

If you have RGB values then you can use:

```
Color c = const Color.fromRGBO(66, 165, 245, 1.0);
```

if you have HEX then you can use default constructor i.e for #ABCDEF use

```
Color myColor = const Color(0xFFABCDEF);
```

Note that the first 2 FF is the alpha channel - transparency. FF means completely visible. If you omit them your color will be fully transparent.