# Flutter how to bind color string

Tags: flutter

I need to bind the color code in a flutter. I have code like this.

```
 color: Color(int.parse(widget.product.colors[i]))
```

Issue is previously i have full hex code in `widget.product.colors[i]` like `0xFF223263` but now i have just  `#223263`. How can I bind this mean add before this

Mean something like

```
 color: Color(int.parse(0xff$widget.product.colors[i]))
```

Mean if I need to add 0xff before the colors so it can show in-app

Comment: You have `#` also?

Comment: yes updated recently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

```
var col = widget.product.colors[i];
var stringCol = "ff" + col.substring(1, 7);
var intCol = int.parse(finalCol, radix : 16);
Color finalCol = new Color(intCol);
```

Use this `finalCol` wherever you want

if it's a text, then

```
Text('Hello World', style = TextStyle(color: finalCol));
```

Voila...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` then concatenate `0xff` with the rest of the hex numbers

Like so

```
Color(int.parse("0xff${widget.product.colors[i].replaceAll("#", "")}"))
```