# How to get a color shade in Flutter from given color?

Tags: flutter

Something like:

```
getColorShade(Color color){
    
    Color shadeOne = color.shade50
    Color shadeTwo = color.shade300
    Color shadeThree = color.shade500
    
    }
```

I do not intend to play with the color alpha here.

Comment: The default colours have shades which you can use like this: `Colors.blue[300];`, but these are hardcoded values. Maybe create a [`HSLColor`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/HSLColor-class.html) and adjust the `lightness`?

Comment: Yes, I've used Colors.blue[300] but would like to get shade for any given color.

Comment: I would try to use `HSLColor` and lightness and try out some values until you get something you like.

Comment: Thanks, will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

by using hex color you can use any range of color that you want right? so by getting help from another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter?rq=1), there is a function which returns a flutter color by sending it a hex number color. here is the function which I use myself:

```
Color hexToColor(String code) {
  return new Color(int.parse(code.substring(1, 7), radix: 16) + 0xFF000000);
}
```