# How can i convert hex color code to color name or rgb value?

Tags: flutter

The thing is i have an hex color code which is pass to another screen and when i go to another screen i wanna convert that hex color code to color name or to rgb value is that possible? need some help here.

```
This is my hex color code value type #ff373334
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter#:~:text=Create%20a%20variable%20of%20type,you%20are%20ready%20to%20go.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple
`new Color(0xFF373334)`
should work

or

```
 Color(0xFF373334).red
    Color(0xFF373334).green
    Color(0xFF373334).blue
```

Comment: no no i want to convert that hex color code to actual rgb value

Comment: @Sujan, did you mean like grey, orange, blue, etc?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

the package [color_models](https://pub.dev/packages/color_models) will help you convert a Hex color to CMYK, HSI, HSL, HSP, HSB, LAB, Oklab, RGB, and XYZ.

It's straightforward to use, and if you need a custom implementation, you can check the repository of the package to see how each model work to convert your Hex color to RGB.

Comment: thanks i found this package and currently trying it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this.

```
   hexStringToColor(String hexColor) {
  hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
  if (hexColor.length == 6) {
    hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
  }
  return Color(int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16));
}
```

Now you can call this function anywhere like this.

```
Color color = hexStringToColor(hexString);
```