# Create a flutter Color object and Compute hex color code for an arbitrary string flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, hex

Most of the time, dynamic Colors in flutter will fetch from the server.
But what if we need to generate a dynamic color just based on title or name?
Is there any way to convert a simple string to a color on **flutter**?
For example:

- input:

```dart
String title = "Lord of the rings";
```

- Output

```dart
Color color = getTitleColor(title);
```

- List item
- List item
- if it needs any package, please add
- if you know a clean way to add among all the project, please add
  if you want to contact me:
  [My resume web page based on flutter web](https://hasanm08.github.io/#/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use hexadecimal color strings in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter)

Comment: @nvoigt no this is for titles and names such as "Lord of rings" or "Amirhassan Amirmahani"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to create a new extension on String model like this

```dart
extension StringColor on String {
  Color textToColor() {
    if(isEmpty){
      return Colors.black;
    }
    var hash = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      hash = codeUnitAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
    }
    return Color(hash + 0xFF000000);
  }
}
```